# How to make ssis excel data source task to not fail even when the file is open and being used by another user?

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that will read excel files from a shared network drive. I am using excel data source task.

In visual studio the task works fine even if the excel file is open and being used by another user.

When I deploy the package to the ssis catalog, and execute, the package fails when the file is open with someone.

Is there any way to make the excel task work even when the file is open?

Answer (score 0):

By default the Excel provider controls this since it doesn't open a file in shared mode.
You can otherwise use a File System Task to copy the Excel file from a shared location to a private one and use it in your Data Flow.

Comment: Yes I have used the copy approach but was wondering if there is any other way to access excel file without locking?